# Word VBA Trim Function

Tags: vba, ms-word, trim

I want to use Trim or Ltrim to change my selection. I have a long If-Then list. the following is a short example

```
With Selection
If .Text = "Since" or .Text = "Since " Then .TypeText Text:= "Because"
If .Text = "since" or .Text = "since " Then .TypeText Text:= "because"
End With
```

How do I trim my selection before the if-then statements? Also, for the above example, is there an easier way to make the appropriate case-sensitive change?

Comment: Should be UCase(Trim(.Text)) = "SINCE"

Answer (score 1):

For the Trimming part:

```
If Trim(.Text) = "Since" Then .TypeText Text:= "Because"
If Trim(.Text) = "since" Then .TypeText Text:= "because"
```

For the capital letter part:

Maybe you could reformat each pair of If-Then using a function, something like this:

```
CheckAndType("since", "because")
```

And then:

```
Function CheckAndType(origin as String, typeText as String)
    If Ucase(Trim(Selection.Text)) = UCase(Trim(origin)) Then
        If StrComp(Left(Selection.Text, 1), UCase(Left(Selection.Text, 1)), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
            Selection.TypeText Text:=LCase(typeText)
        Else
            Selection.TypeText Text:= UCase(Left(typeText, 1)) & LCase(Right(typeText, Len(typeText) - 1)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Code not tested. Any doubt/clarification, just ask.

Comment: This seems like it would clean up my code a lot. I just don't get how to implement it. Once the function is created, where do I create the list of CheckAndType ("since", "because") ("as", "because")

Comment: Thanks. I worked out the Function, now I'm trying to figure out how to make it add a comment (by calling a macro) when specific words in my list of 'Call CheckAndType' are used 'Call CheckAndType("Since", "Because")
Application.Run MacroName:="Normal.NewMacros.CommentRW5"' This is not working as intended.

Comment: @WritePlace to call a Macro you need to use `Call NewMacros.CommentRW5`